# How to generate 3 pulses of varying lengths with an FPGA and Verilog?

Tags: arduino, fpga, verilog, clock, intel-fpga

I am trying to generate 3 pulses of 2 different lengths at specific times using an Arduino MKR Vidor 4000 which has an Intel Cyclone 10 on board.

I need to generate one pulse with 5 µs length followed by one of 10 µs length and then another of 5 µs length. These pulses should be separated by 1 ms.

As in RF signal in this image: [image: modelsim screenshot]

I find that when I run my code the pulses are actually about 1000 times larger than the simulation, this does not make sense to me as there is no delay in the real code.

I originally tried with if statements then converted to the following cases statement and found I got the same result.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    case(counter)
    ((mz_start_time <= counter) & (counter < (pi_2 + mz_start_time))) : rf  = 1; // first pi/2 pulse
    (( pi_start <= counter) & (counter < interval_2_start)) : rf = 1; // pi pulse
    ((second_pi_2_start <= counter) & (counter < end_time)) : rf = 1; //second pi/2 pulse
    default : rf = 0;
    endcase
    counter = counter + 1; 
end
```

I thought this may be something to do with delay propagation; however, quartus gives no issues.

EDIT:
here is the original if statement code (requested by Dave Tweed)

```
input clk; // fpga clock as input
output rf; // outputs to rf controller

integer counter = 0; 
integer pi_2 = 333;  // this changes the frequency, it is the 
number of clock cycles for which the pin is low or high. 
integer pi;
assign pi = pi_2 * 2;  // sets pi pulse to be twice the length of the pi over 2 

integer dead_time = 5; //multiples of 5, micro seconds
assign dead_counts = (dead_time/5) * 333;
integer interval = 1000;
assign interval_counts = (interval / 5) * 333;


always @(posedge clk) begin
    // deadtime at start. 
    if (counter <= dead_counts) begin
        $display("deadtime");
        rf = 0;
        counter <= counter + 1; 
    end 
    // pi/2 pulse 
    else if ( dead_counts < counter <= (pi_2 + dead_counts)) begin 
        $display("pi/2");
        rf = 1;
        counter <= counter + 1;
    end 
    // first interval
    else if ((dead_counts + pi_2) < counter <= (dead_counts + pi_2 + interval_counts)) begin 
        $display("interval 1");
        rf = 0;
        counter <= counter + 1; 
    end 
    // pi pulse
     else if ((dead_counts + pi_2 + interval_counts) < counter <= (dead_counts + pi_2 + interval_counts + pi)) begin
         $display("pi pulse");
         rf = 1;
        counter <= counter + 1; 
    end
end
```

Comment: What is your input clock frequency?

Comment: Maybe the clock is 1000 times slower than you thought?

Comment: I'd like to see the original `if` statement-based code. That `case` statement you're using doesn't look at all right to me.

Comment: The MKR Vidor is supposed to have a clock frequency of 48 MHz @BenVoigt

Comment: @DaveTweed I have updated the post for you to include the if statement based code

Comment: @solomonsanderson: It doesn't matter what crystal you have on the board, it matters what is the frequency of the `clk` input to this block of logic.

Comment: I think I am giving it the frequency of the internal oscillator of the board, is that different to the 48 MHz clock the board has?

Comment: One comment on the case statement version:  You should use && instead of & here because you are testing boolean (or single-bit) values.  The single & is used for bit-wise operations.  However, what you have will work in this case.  You can get unexpected results if you are casual about syntax like this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple alternative.  I'm not sure what all your objectives are, but believe this logic will do what you ask.  I assumed the clock here was 1 MHz.  If the derived signals rf_high and rf_low are both de-asserted, rf will retain its last value.

This code will generate the desired sequence once when "run" is asserted.  If you de-assert, and re-assert "run", the pattern will be generated again.

```
module pulse_gen (
    run,     // Enable pulse generation
    clk,     // clock - assumed to be 1MHz
    rf       // pulse output signal.
);

input  run;
input  clk;
output rf;

wire rf_high;
wire rf_low;
wire counter_rst;
wire [11:0] max_count = 11'd2020;

reg [11:0] counter;
reg        rf;

assign rf_high = counter == 0 || counter == 1005 || counter == 2015;

assign rf_low  = counter == 5 || counter == 1015 || counter == 2020;     

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (run) begin
            
        if (rf_high) rf <= 1;  
        if (rf_low)  rf <= 0;

        if (counter == max_count)  counter <= max_count;
        else                       counter <= counter + 1;
    end
    else begin   // don't run
        counter <= 0;
        rf      <= 0;
    end
end

endmodule
```

Comment: Shouldn't rf_high become signal_rise and rf_low becom e signal_fall?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I did not double check.  I updated the code, keeping the rf_high and rf_low variables.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it possible to have it so that the pattern does not repeat @Troutdog

Comment: Yes, one way to do that is to latch the counter value when it reaches 2020.  So, instead of resetting the counter, you latch it at the end of the sequence:   
assign counter_max = 2020;

if (counter == counter_max) counter <= counter_max;
else                                        counter <= counter + 1;

sorry if the formatting is not clear.  I can edit the answer above and put this in a code block if you want.

Comment: @solomonsanderson:  I edited the code block to do what you asked.   It will generate the pulse train once if the signal run is asserted.  This can be repeated as desired by toggling the run signal.